# Sorting student test scores in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I am given an integer, N, which is the number of test scores that will be inputted. For each line, N, there will be a student name followed their test score. I need to compute the sum of their test scores & print the the second-smallest student's name.

Comment: I see H's test score to be 4 in your input.

Comment: There are students with duplicate scores and B has score 6 and E has score 3 (not 7). Also H has 4

Comment: You must add them. It is the sum of their scores (see how H has 4 and then later it says H has 5). 4 + 5 = 9.

Comment: I see the output should be Z which is 4

Comment: I fixed one mistake in the test data.

Comment: All of the student test scores are summed for that individual student. I must print out the second-smallest student score.

Comment: Instead of adding somany if checks, directly take the student name as key and sum of their scores as values into  Map. Then just sort the map by values and then take the second student name to show the output

Comment: Hi, I think I did something similar to this but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: can you please show us your work

Comment: yes I have updated the original post.

Comment: Get rid of those case statements.  As @Nishank hinted, use a map - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java  .

Comment: `Arrays.sort(students);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I would do is create an array of classes for the students. The class would have two instance variables for the name and score. Then when all the input is done, all you need to do is get them. Here is the code that I came up with for that exact thing.

```
import java.util.*;

public class testScores {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        Student[] students = new Student[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            students[i] = new Student();
            System.out.print("Enter the student's name");
            students[i].setName(scan.next());
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the student's score");
            students[i].setScore(scan.nextInt());
            scan.nextLine();
        }

        int total = 0;
        int smallest_name = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            total+=students[i].getScore();
            if(students[i].getName().length() < students[smallest_name].getName().length())
                smallest_name = i;
        }

        int second_smallest = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(students[i].getName().length() > students[smallest_name].getName().length() && students[i].getName().length() < students[second_smallest].getName().length())
                second_smallest = i;
        }

        System.out.println("The sum of the scores is: " + total);
        System.out.println("The second smallest name is: " + students[second_smallest].getName());

    }
}

class Student{

    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Student(){}

    public void setScore(int n){
        score = n;
    }

    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup, I am working on getting those out, I will repost in a second.

Comment: That now outputs the second smallest name